# Merging git develop branch to master using Jenkins after Artifactory Release Staging

Tags: git, jenkins, artifactory, git-merge

Is there any feature/plugin or settings in Jenkins to automatically merge the develop branch into Master branch after I performed the Artifactory Release Staging?
Currently, I'm doing the git merge master manually after published the modules via Artifactory Release Staging.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that I'm aware of no. I do it manually too, wrapping everything in the `sshagent` plugin to handle authentication against the remote repository:

```
sshagent (credentials: [credentials]) {
    sh "git checkout master"
    sh "git merge -Xtheirs --no-edit develop"
    sh "git push"
}
```

Comment: hey @DevAntoine, can this piece of code added into Artifactory Release Staging? Mean I just need one click, then Jenkins do all the jobs -> update release version, update next development version, release modules, and also merge to master. Appreciated for your answer.

Comment: @Callie I don't think so. This snippet lives inside your Jenkinsfile. I'm not used to Artifactory Release Staging. I'd say your pipeline should run the Artifactory thing and once it's done run another stage where you merge develop into master with the code above.